# Angularjs architecture

Tags: angularjs, architecture

I'm trying to wrap my head around inheritance and reusable widgets in AngualarJS (to which I'm completely new) and would really like if someone can help out with pointers for my problem:

I have a two page (route) app. Both these pages needs to be user configurable, both when it comes to which widgets to show and also more specifically for the tables widgets picking which columns of the data they hold should be shown.

What I do is that at page load I fetch a user specific JSON configuration from a REST API. This JSON will look something like:

```
{
  "widgets": [ 
     { "type":"TableWidget", "columns":["title", "from_year"], "dataSource":"/api/movies"},
     { "type":"TableWidget", "columns":["name", "country"], "dataSource":"/api/actors"},
     { "type":"TableWidget", "columns":["name", "age"], "dataSource":"/api/actors"}
  ]
}
```

This means the user wants three tables displayed, two of which uses the same data source, except just showing different columns (in reality this won't be the case but rather a graph or something else using the same data but displaying it differently).

Now, what I'd like to do here is to create a generic TableWidget with the look and feel I want to the tables. It should be tied to a data source and some things should be configurable. In object hierarchy I'd like to create some sort of BaseWidget type which has properties all my widgets will share. I'd then want the TableWidget to inherit the common properties and also adds table specific properties.

The flow I envision in the app is then basically:

1. Get user configuration
2. Loop through the configuration and instantiate each widget the user wants to see
3. Place the widgets in the page draw them

This obviously isn't using the directives since the html will not know about the user configuration. I can't know a load time what the page looks like and I don't know where the data will be fetched from. A kind of similar implementation is Kibana, but their code base is too massive for me to have the time to wrap my head around in time for me to solve my problem.

Pointers to documentation and similar problems and solutions would be appreciated. I keep finding very simple tutorials and examples, and searching for architecture I only find posts about the recommended directory structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider using angular fragments directive from angular ui: [ui-utils](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/). It allows for embedding fragments of HTML code inside a special "ui-fragment" directive. You could model your generic table using normal templating and then - based on dataSource - display different layouts inside. To display many tables, "ng-repeat" directive could be used.

As for special looks and properties - please refer to creating custom directives: [directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). It enables creating parametrized directives and could be used to create custom html elements that look different based on provided model.